# Expected number of tosses to get a head from a coin using integration formulae?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I recently started learning Expectation Probability , first of all Any Good resources to study it will be appreciated if any one can share 
What I have learnt so far the expected  value of some Unknown Variable say $x$ be $ E(x)$ 
which boils down this equation  $ E(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x*P(x) dx $ where P(x) is the Probability of some specific $x$ . 
So I wanted to find the Expected Number of tosses to Get a  Heads from an Unbiased Coin So I used this equation to solve it 
$E(Getting Heads) =>  \int_{0}^\infty\dfrac{x}{2^x}  dx$ , **IT IS A PRETTY STANDARD RESULT THAT E(GETTING  HEADS) = 2, But this integral is giving me another answer , which is $\dfrac{1}{\ln^2\left(2\right)}$ 
 Can Anyone tell me where am I going wrong with understanding stuff.

Comment: I found the book by Dekking et al to very helpful when I was studying Probability in an introductory course.

Comment: Thanks for that :D  @P.J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral formula you're using only applies to *continuous* random variables with probability *density* function $p(x)$. But the "number of coin tosses before heads appears" is a *discrete* random variable because it only takes integer values. The expected value of a discrete random variable is $E(X)=\sum_x x\cdot P(X=x)$, taking the sum over all possible values $x$.

Comment: How can one decide the limits of this summation specifically in this question ?

Comment: What are the possible values for $X$? $X$ is the number of coin tosses you perform before heads appears.

Comment: There may be infinite moves before a head appears , How will I solve this summation to get an answer 2  ?

Comment: The random variable - Number of moves/ tosses required to get 1 success for repeated bernoulli trials - has [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: Yep, so the sum should go from $0$ to $\infty$. For random variables like this, the following is useful: $E(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nP(X=n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^nP(X=n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty P(X=n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X\ge k)$.

Comment: Thank you so much @Karl But I didnot get how you are breaking this stuff into a double summation It will be great if you can include it in your answer

Comment: The point of that step is to get rid of the $n$ by writing $nA=\sum_{k=1}^nA$. The calculus trick in sasquire's answer is another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

> How will I solve this summation to get an answer 2 ?

From your phrasing of the question, I'm assuming that you threw the coin $n$ times and got tails each time, and then you got heads on the $(n+1)$-th time.  The probability of this occurring is $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.  So you want to find the value of
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^n} $$

There is a trick for solving this kind of sum, assuming that you already know the sum of a geometric series and some basic calculus.  (If not, there are other ways of proving it, but the only ways I know are conceptually more difficult.)

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n + 1) x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} x^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1} \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \\
\end{align} $$

The second line (moving the derivative outside the sum) is actually nontrivial, but it is okay in this instance because the sum converges uniformly.  (This is a technical detail that may or may not be interesting to you.)  The third line is just summing a geometric series, and the fourth line is basic calculus and some algebra.

Plugging in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ recovers your original problem.  The answer is
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n + 1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2} = 2 $$

Comment: Note that the factor of 1/2 is there to normalize the probabilities. (The sum of all the probabilities of the individual events has to be 1.) what is that  ?

Comment: @KartikBhatia You wrote the probability as $\frac{1}{2^x}$.  My interpretation of that is: "The probability of throwing the coin $x$ times and getting tails and then throwing the $(x+1)$th time and getting a heads is $\frac{1}{2^x}$."  But this isn't correct.  There are several ways to see this.  One way is that you actually threw $(x+1)$ times, and the probability of each event was $\frac{1}{2}$, so the probability of the sequence is $\frac{1}{2^{x+1}}$.  Another way to see it is that the probabilities must add to be 1.  $\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x} = 2$, so you need a $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Cool I understand it completely now , This calculus trick was cool thanks :D

Comment: Ok, great.  I just realized that there are two very minor errors that cancel each other out in what I wrote.  You actually made $n+1$ throws, so the numerator in the sum should be $n+1$, not $n$.  And the derivative of $x^{n+1}$ is actually $nx^n$!  Will fix now.

Comment: Yeah and the factor of 2 is really not bothering us here the reason being the failure is also 1/2 And winning on that very N+1 th throw is also determined by probability of 1/2 that's my Interpretation

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x*2^{-x} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{5}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{7}{128}+\frac{8}{256}+\frac{9}{512}+\frac{10}{1024}+\frac{11}{2048}+\frac{12}{4096}\dots$

$= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{16}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{16}{64}+\frac{22}{256}+\frac{28}{1024}+\frac{34}{4096}+\dots$

$= \frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{32}+\frac{2}{64}+\frac{2}{128}+\frac{2}{256}+\frac{2}{512}+\frac{2}{4096}+\dots$

Here another and maybe a more easy way to see it this way that the picture and the adjusted line of fractions is correct:

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x*2^{-x} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{5}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{7}{128}+\frac{8}{256}+\frac{9}{512}+\frac{10}{1024}+\frac{11}{2048}+\frac{12}{4096}+\frac{13}{8192}+\frac{14}{16384}+\frac{15}{32768}+\frac{16}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{16}{32}+\frac{16}{32}+\frac{12}{32}+\frac{8}{32}+\frac{5}{32}+\frac{48}{512}+\frac{28}{512}+\frac{16}{512}+\frac{9}{512}+\frac{80}{8192}+\frac{44}{8192}+\frac{24}{8192}+\frac{13}{8192}+\frac{56}{65536}+\frac{30}{65536}+\frac{16}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{256}{512}+\frac{256}{512}+\frac{192}{512}+\frac{128}{512}+\frac{80}{512}+\frac{48}{512}+\frac{448}{8192}+\frac{256}{8192}+\frac{144}{8192}+\frac{80}{8192}+\frac{352}{65536}+\frac{192}{65536}+\frac{104}{65536}+\frac{56}{65536}+\frac{30}{65536}+\frac{16}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{960}{512}+\frac{928}{8192}+\frac{750}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{122880}{65536}+\frac{7424}{65536}+\frac{750}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{131054}{65536}+\dots\approx 1,999725341796875$

$=\frac{65536}{65536}+\frac{65518}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{65518}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{32768}{65536}+\frac{32750}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{16384}{65536}+\frac{16366}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{8192}{65536}+\frac{8174}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{4096}{65536}+\frac{4078}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{2}{32}+\frac{2048}{65536}+\frac{2030}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{2}{32}+\frac{2}{64}+\frac{1024}{65536}+\frac{1006}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{2}{32}+\frac{2}{64}+\frac{2}{128}+\frac{512}{65536}+\frac{494}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{2}{32}+\frac{2}{64}+\frac{2}{128}+\frac{2}{256}+\frac{256}{65536}+\frac{238}{65536}+\dots$

$=\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{8}+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{2}{32}+\frac{2}{64}+\frac{2}{128}+\frac{2}{256}+\frac{2}{512}+\frac{128}{65536}+\frac{110}{65536}+\dots$

[image: Here is a simple way to understand it.]

The integral formula will result in some small deviations due to irrationalities of it.

Comment: I agree with the lower square, but the upper square (for $\sum x 2^{-x}$) is completely wrong. First of all, adding the lengths on the right side of the square implies $\frac{2}{2}+ \frac{2}{4} = \sqrt{2}$!  Also, what part represents the term $\frac{3}{8}$, for example?

Comment: I added it above, you can use this same principle of renormalization for all kind of stuff with any amount of dimensions, like Entropy of dimension x or spheres as well.

Comment: Is still not at all clear what you did between the second to last line and the last line.  (I won’t ask about spheres or dimension x...)

Comment: Those are just fractions of powers of two, you can adjust the denominators in any combination you like, beginning at any position you like and simply doing some fraction calculus. I'll add one alternative calculation, maybe it wil be very easy to see then.

Comment: I think you are doing the convolution of two geometric series to get the right result, but you are leaving out the most important step, where you actually break up each term and then rearrange things, so I can’t be sure.  (And my earlier objection regarding the side of the square was based on misreading the labels.). But no one will be able to follow this answer without doing the term-breaking step explicitly.

Comment: Sure you, can look for some tricky rearrangements, quite sure there are some very elegant solutions on wikipedia.

Comment: I am saying that your answer is incomprehensible as it is. But I will stop trying to convince you.

Comment: You've shown that the sum converges numerically but it's not clear that the arithmetic you're doing is generalizable at all.  Numerics are fine, but they're not a proof.

Comment: The way to actually do the calculation you are trying to show for the full *infinite* series is the following. $\left(\sum_n x^n\right)^2 = \sum_m x^m \sum_n x^n = \sum_m \sum_n x^{m+n} = \sum_k \sum_{n=0}^k x^k = \sum_k (k + 1) x^k$, where implied summation limits are $0$ to $\infty$ and $k=m+n$ is a new simplifying dummy variable.  Plugging in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ on both sides gives $\sum_k k 2^{-k} = \sum_k (k + 1) 2^{-k} - \sum_k 2^{-k} = \left( \sum_k 2^{-k} \right)^2 - \sum_k 2^{-k} = 2^2 - 2 = 2$.

Comment: You're right, but as my intention by writing it down wasn't to show the convergence of the sum (I already showed the convergence in the picture), my intention was only to show that the sum can be easily rearranged and that the values in the picture are correctly mapped to the sum, I mean the convergence of it gets trivialized by visualizing it this way, or doesn't it?

Comment: You start with one sum, $\sum_x x 2^{-x}$.  Then you claim that it is equivalent to another sum, which you do not write in summation notation, but the terms are equivalent to $\sum_x 2^{-x+1}$.  Then you show the second sum in a picture.  The thing I am objecting to is the "claim" part, the connection between the first sum and the second sum.  Showing that they both converge to the same value numerically is not a proof that the two sums are equivalent.  But anyway, I don't think that we are going to agree, so I will go back to my former stance and stop trying to convince you.

Comment: Maybe you're right though, I'm quite sure I can proof it by induction, I'll add a complete formal proof on weekend.

Comment: Proof using Induction will be Nice to see :D Also I did not get this convergence stuff but this visualization using square is great I just have a small doubt about it The lower square sure converges back and shows an approximation but this approximation on the upper square is kinda hazyy If You could give a one liner what it is doing? how did that boil down to a square of size √2

Comment: This is quite interesting, never thought about it, this could actually even explain why the Integral formula has a small deviation and results slightly above 2.